# ng-repeat inside ng-if scope seems to run ng-if multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have been working on this issue for some time now where I have a nested ng-repeat as below with two ng-if's.

```
section(ng-controller="SideBarController as sidebar")
  div.sas-sidebar.navbar-default.sidebar(role="navigation")
    div.navbar-default.sidebar(role="navigation")
      div.sidebar-nav.navbar-collapse
        ul.nav.in#side-menu
          li(ng-repeat="link in links")
            a(href="#" ng-click="loadContent(link.url)" ng-if="!hasSubLink(link)") {{link.name}}
            a(href="#" ng-if="hasSubLink(link)") {{link.name}}
              span.fa.arrow(class="{{link.className}}")
              ul.nav.nav-second-level
                li(ng-repeat="sublink in link.sub")
                  a(href="#" ng-click="loadContent(sublink.url)") {{sublink.name}}
  div#page-wrapper(style="min-height: 1120px" ng-include="pageContent")
```

But here is what I get in return:

```
<ul style="" aria-expanded="true" class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
  <!-- ngIf: hasSubLink(link) -->
  <a class="ng-scope" href="#" ng-if="hasSubLink(link)"></a>
  <!-- end ngIf: hasSubLink(link) -->
  <!-- ngRepeat: sublink in link.sub -->
    <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="sublink in link.sub">
    <!-- ngIf: hasSubLink(link) -->
      <a class="ng-scope" href="#" ng-if="hasSubLink(link)"></a>
    <!-- end ngIf: hasSubLink(link) -->
      <a class="ng-binding" href="#" 

...
```

My question is: Why is the ng-if being run inside my 'sublink' ng-repeat if the ng-if is supposed to be in an outer scope?

My goal is to have code that follows this logic:

```
loop item in set1:
    if item.question:
        print a1
    elif:
        print a2
        loop item2 in item1.subset:
           print a3
```

Comment: Don´t know exactly why you have thios behaviour but ng-if is creating an own scope. You could try to use `ng-show/ng-hide` instead and tell the results.

Comment: its normal, whenever you execute function in angular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so discovered that this was easily fixed by moving the inner `ul` tag out one space. Which I think still relates to Ivan's answer about nested a tags. It looks like my incorrect use of `ul` / `li` was throwing a really difficult error to debug.

```
section(ng-controller="SideBarController as sidebar")
  div.sas-sidebar.navbar-default.sidebar(role="navigation")
    div.navbar-default.sidebar(role="navigation")
      div.sidebar-nav.navbar-collapse.in
        ul.nav.in#side-menu
          li(ng-repeat="link in sidebar.links")
            a(href="#" ng-if="!sidebar.hasSubLink(link)" ng-click="sidebar.loadContent(link.url)") {{link.name}}
            a(href="#" ng-if="sidebar.hasSubLink(link)") {{link.name}}
              span.fa.arrow(class="{{link.className}}")
            ul.nav.nav-second-level.collapse
              li(ng-repeat="sublink in link.sub")
                a(href="#" ng-click="sidebar.loadContent(sublink.url)") {{sublink.name}}
  div#page-wrapper(style="min-height: 1120px" ng-include="pageContent")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced same issue, and what I found so far is: this weird behavior happens because of [html 5 parsing algorythm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing), because, according to w3c, you are not allowed to have interactive elements nested inside of each other (e.g. `<a>` inside of `<a>`). Thus parser closes outer `<a>` as soon as it sees inner `<a>` and reinjects reformatted element, according to [adoption agency algorythm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#adoption-agency-algorithm) (to be honest I didn't understand much from w3c docs, just the main picture, so don't judge me hard :-).
Long story short, I have managed to fix this issue by reformatting my html so that to `<a>`'s are not nested inside of each other.